# Ansible JSON output with debug=ON

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

When I run a playbook on which I register the command output onto a register and assign that to msg with debug true with my ansible.cfg as below
stdout_callback = json
retry_files_enabled = False

I get the desired output of "hosts" 2 times.

ANSIBLE VERSION

```
ansible 2.5.2
```

COMPONENT NAME

```
module: shell
```

A sample task looks like below :

```
- name: MongoDB Auth check
  script: files/mongoAuthCheck.sh
  register: mongoAuthCheck_out
  changed_when: false

- debug:
   msg: "{{ mongoAuthCheck_out.stdout_lines }}"
```

CONFIGURATION

```
ANSIBLE_NOCOWS(xx/xx/xx/ansible.cfg) = True
CACHE_PLUGIN(xx/xx/xx/ansible.cfg) = jsonfile
DEFAULT_GATHERING(xx/xx/xx/ansible.cfg) = smart
DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK(xx/xx/xx/ansible.cfg) = json
HOST_KEY_CHECKING(xx/xx/xx/ansible.cfg) = False
RETRY_FILES_ENABLED(/xx/xx/xx/ansible.cfg) = False
```

EXPECTED RESULTS

```
"tasks": [
                {
                    "hosts": {
                        "10.140.0.15": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                            "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                            "changed": false, 
                            "msg": [
                                "Unit mongod.service could not be found.", 
                                "[INFO] Mongo service not running"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "10.140.0.18": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                            "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                            "changed": false, 
                            "msg": [
                                "Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set.  Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly. locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid", 
                                "[VULNERABLE] MongoDB auth is NOT enabled"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "10.140.0.22": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                            "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                            "changed": false, 
                            "msg": [
                                "[INFO] Mongo service not running"
                            ]
                        }
                    }, 
                    "task": {
                        "id": "d6002031-f201-2ec3-be9f-000000000026", 
                        "name": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

ACTUAL RESULTS

```
"tasks": [
                {
                    "hosts": {
                        "10.140.0.15": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                            "changed": false, 
                            "rc": 0, 
                            "stderr": "Shared connection to 10.140.0.15 closed.\r\n", 
                            "stdout": "Unit mongod.service could not be found.\r\n[INFO] Mongo service not running\r\n", 
                            "stdout_lines": [
                                "Unit mongod.service could not be found.", 
                                "[INFO] Mongo service not running"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "10.140.0.18": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                            "changed": false, 
                            "rc": 0, 
                            "stderr": "Shared connection to 10.140.0.18 closed.\r\n", 
                            "stdout": "Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set.  Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly. locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid\r\n[VULNERABLE] MongoDB auth is NOT enabled\r\n", 
                            "stdout_lines": [
                                "Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set.  Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly. locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid", 
                                "[VULNERABLE] MongoDB auth is NOT enabled"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "10.140.0.22": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                            "changed": false, 
                            "rc": 0, 
                            "stderr": "Shared connection to 10.140.0.22 closed.\r\n", 
                            "stdout": "[INFO] Mongo service not running\r\n", 
                            "stdout_lines": [
                                "[INFO] Mongo service not running"
                            ]
                        }
                    }, 
                    "task": {
                        "id": "d6002031-f201-2ec3-be9f-000000000025", 
                        "name": "MongoDB Auth check"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "hosts": {
                        "10.140.0.15": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                            "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                            "changed": false, 
                            "msg": [
                                "Unit mongod.service could not be found.", 
                                "[INFO] Mongo service not running"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "10.140.0.18": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                            "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                            "changed": false, 
                            "msg": [
                                "Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set.  Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly. locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid", 
                                "[VULNERABLE] MongoDB auth is NOT enabled"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "10.140.0.22": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                            "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                            "changed": false, 
                            "msg": [
                                "[INFO] Mongo service not running"
                            ]
                        }
                    }, 
                    "task": {
                        "id": "d6002031-f201-2ec3-be9f-000000000026", 
                        "name": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

How do I get the expected output ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It looks like you *are* seeing the expected output? Your "expected results" only shows output for one task, and of course there are *two* tasks in your playbook, which is why you have two result dictionaries in your output, but otherwise the `msg` keys from your `debug` tasks appear as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are running your playbook with some higher level of verbosity enabled (I'd guess you're running something like `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -v` instead of just `ansible-playbook playbook.yml).

Try running the `ansible-playbook` command with no verbosity flag set.